# Cover vinyl asbestos floor tile without making later flooring harder

Tags: flooring, asbestos, polyurethane, vinyl-flooring, epoxy

I have a kitchen with 9"x9" vinyl floor tiles that I have just found out contain asbestos.  Though they are at first glance in sound condition (only a very few small chips, all well-adhered, etc), looking closer there is a fair amount of scuffing and small scratches from everyday wear and tear which with 2 kids I do not like at all.  All that abraded material has to go somewhere...

The long-term plan - when we can afford it - is to rip out the kitchen and probably put on an extension.  But I want to do something now to stop the wear and tear on the tiles - and ideally encapsulate them.  How can I best do this without (a) tearing out the existing kitchen units and (b) making a future remodelling much more difficult?  This area might eventually be carpeted, tiled or lino.  I don't much care what it looks like in the meantime.  It is VAT on top of concrete; there's no visible black glue so I imagine they were peel and stick.
Options I have thought of:

- Epoxy floor paint.  Would do the job, but I understand it's very hard to put anything else on top of this later without scarifying the surface (bad idea on asbestos!) - and presumably this would make removing the tiles really hard too
- Polyurethane floor paint.  May be better to lay new flooring on later, but will it adhere, and it also sounds horrible to work with (respirator needed?)
- May be a crazy idea, but can I just get some cheap vinyl flooring and lay it without sticking it down?
- I can't see trying to put down any form of screed around the existing units working
- How much difference would vinyl floor polish/sealer make?  As far as I can tell, these are usually wax-based so are unlikely to add a lot of abrasion resistance.

Comment: Cover with a floating floor of snap lock vinyl planks.

Comment: Thanks @JimStewart .  That's what I did (although when I moved the appliances the tiles were in such a state that I ended up getting them removed first).  Would have worked great though - easy to lay, reasonably inexpensive and easy to get up again later.  If you want to answer I'll accept it.